# Object changes inside array but stays unchanged on page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table which is made by `ng-repeat`. That part which doesnt get refreshed is below;

```
<tbody class="defTbody" ng-repeat="activity in activityList track by activity.ActivityID">
     <tr class="{{activity.DetailExpanded == true ? 'shown' : ''}}">
         <td>
             <a ng-if="!activity.DetailExpanded" ng-click="activity.DetailExpanded = true"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus-circle txt-color-green fa-lg"></i></a>
             <a ng-if="activity.DetailExpanded" ng-click="activity.DetailExpanded = false"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-minus-circle txt-color-red fa-lg"></i></a>

         </td>
         <td style="font-size:smaller">
             <a ng-click="getActivityStatements(activity.ActivityID)" style="cursor: pointer;">
                 {{activity.PlanDateTime}} / {{activity.ActivityType_DisplayName}}
                 <br />
                 <small class="text-muted"><i>{{activity.ActivityID}}<i></i></i></small>
             </a>
         </td>
         <td style="font-size:smaller">
             {{activity.ParentActivityDisplayName}}
             <br />
             <small class="text-muted"><i>{{activity.ParentActivityID}}<i></i></i></small>
         </td>
         <td>{{activity.Customer_DisplayName}}</td>

         <td>{{activity.ActivityStatus_DisplayName}}</td>
         <td>
             {{activity.StatusReason}}
             <br />
             {{activity.StatusReasonNote}}
         </td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

`$scope.activityList` is fine, it gets populated correctly. This is how I change an item in activiyList

```
$scope.UpdateActivityListItem = function (activityID, prevResponseDetail) {

        var url = "/api/activity/GetActivityResponse?activityID=" + activityID;

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url
        }).then(function successCallback(result) {
            var response = result.data;

            if (response.Status == "SUCCESS") {
                var activity = $scope.activityList.filter(activity => activity.ActivityID == activityID)[0];
                var renewedAct = response.Detail[0];
                activity = renewedAct;
                $scope.$apply();

                console.log("yenilenmiş aktivite:" +$scope.activityList)

                $('#modalActivityDetail').modal('hide');
                console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.activityList));
                $scope.addSpinnerClass(spinner);
            }
            else {
                console.log("fail");
            }
        },
        function errorCallback(result) {
            console.log("error");
        }
        );
    };
```

I confirmed in debug that item gets "updated" nicely but in screen it stays same.

I thought this was kind of a problem whicj $scope.$apply() can solve but adding it (as shown in code piece above) caused this problem

```
Error: error:inprog
Action Already In Progress

$digest already in progress
```

What else can I do?

PS: This is written in Angular JS 1.0

Comment: where are you updating activityList?

Comment: I'm not updating the whole list, just updating an item inside list.

Comment: Why do you need `$scope.$apply` here? Your `$scope` function and `$http` is part of the digest cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this, You are filtering activityList and updating a filtered array (result) first element not activityList array.

```
var renewedAct = response.Detail[0];
for (let index = 0; index < $scope.activityList.length; index++) {
    const activity = $scope.activityList[index];
    if (activity.ActivityID == activityID) {
        $scope.activityList[index] = renewedAct;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that even without looping again using `splice` **with a single line**

Here is the code,

```
  var activity = $scope.activityList.filter(activity => activity.ActivityID == activityID)[0];
  var index = $scope.activityList.indexOf(activity);
  var renewedAct = response.Detail[0];
  activity = renewedAct;

  $scope.activityList.splice(index, 1, activity)
```

**Note:** The above line removes that element at that place and adds your new element.

Comment: I tried and this works too, too bad I already selected an answer.

Comment: its ok, I added this because it is an optimized solution.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling $apply please check weather the digest cycle is busy or not.

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
  //$digest or $apply
}
```

---------EDIT------
A new, powerful method has been added to any $scope: $evalAsync. Basically, it will execute its callback within the current digest cycle if one is occurring, otherwise a new digest cycle will start executing the callback.
Try this:
In these cases and all the others where you had a !$scope.$$phase, be sure to use `$scope.$evalAsync( callback )` do all related changes in callback.

Comment: Page still stays same and needs refreshing to see the updated data.